# More vertices for circles

Tags: physics, vertices

I just added a sprite-circle to a 2D-Game with physics. I just realized that the circle has only very few vertices. Can I increase the vertex count of the circle by using GUI only?
I am using the LTS 2020.3.29f1 version of Unity

Comment: What problem are you actually encountering? Is it the image quality that you have issue with?

Answer (score 0):

A sprite does not have vertices, it has pixels.
You can use a higher resolution texture if you wish to make the sprite look better when scaled up.

If your concern is accuracy of the collider's hitbox, then you can't do better than the CircleCollider2D as it has effectively infinite resolution in respect to a perfect circle.

Comment: Well... I as assuming some things in the wrong way. I realized that while reading your answer. I added a 2D circle 'sprite'. Now, while toying around with that circle I added a material to that object and I was astonished that:
https://postimg.cc/F1Zw8D2b

So I assumed a very basic circle is used to get the sprite unto an object. For having a smoother expierience I wanted to increase the vertex count... But now I know I guess I should use 3D object for 2D as well...

Comment: Can you include an screenshot of the inspector window of your "circle sprite". It doesn't seem like you're using a sprite at all, a sprite is a 2D image which has no vertices. It looks like you're using a mesh of some sort. Does your object have a MeshRenderer or a SpriteRenderer component?